# Html to ansi colored terminal text

Tags: html, terminal, ansi-colors

I am under Linux and I want to fetch an html page from the web and then output it on terminal. I found out that `html2text` essentially does the job, but it converts my html to a plain text whereas I would better convert it into ansi colored text in the spirit of `ls --color=auto`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 19):

The `elinks` browser can do that. Other text browsers such as `lynx` or `w3m` might be able to do that as well.

```
elinks -dump -dump-color-mode 1 http://example.com/
```

the above example provides a text version of `http://example.com/` using 16 colors. The output format can be customized further depending on need.

The `-dump` option enables the dump mode, which just prints the whole page as text, with the link destinations printed out in a kind of "email-style".

`-dump-color-mode 1` enables the coloring of the output using the 16 basic terminal colors. Depending on the value and the capabilities of the terminal emulator this can be up to ~16 million (True Color). The values are documented in [elinks.conf(5)](http://elinks.or.cz/documentation/manpages/elinks.conf.5.html).

The colors used for output can be configured as well, which is documented in [elinks.conf(5)](http://elinks.or.cz/documentation/manpages/elinks.conf.5.html) as well.

Comment: Note that `elinks` does not automatically reset the terminal colors, resulting any subsequent output (from a script or terminal) to be the same color as the end of the `elinks` output until a new color code is encountered. You can reset manually by executing `tput sgr0` after `elinks`.

Answer (score 0):

The [w3m browser](http://w3m.sourceforge.net/) supports [coloring the output text](http://ostatic.com/w3m/screenshot/1).

Comment: well, `lynx` also does but I only need to output the page and not to browse it.

Comment: You don't have to. `w3m` has a `-dump`-like option too, and `elinks` does as well. It's just a matter of choosing the one you are most comfortable with.

Comment: @davrieb, any idea how to get one of the browsers to dump in color?

Comment: @sarmold: Not from the top of my head, but yes. I will provide details in a separate answer for better discoverability.

Comment: @davrieb, w3m [0.5.3, 2018] -dump suppresses colored output

Answer (score 0):

You can use the lynx browser to output the text using this command.

```
lynx -dump http://example.com
```

Comment: Any idea how to get `lynx -dump` to also include color? At least on my distro, `lynx` is compiled against `ncurses`, and uses `ncurses` completely to determine when to use color; I couldn't get it to dump color output.

Comment: I tried `lynx -dump somefile.html < <( echo -n qj) > out; cat out` and variants thereof to no avail. Just to let you know that doesn’t work either. So unless you hack `ncurses`… But then installing `elinks` is probably less of a hassle again. ;)